# PHP Class Syntax Error - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason whenever I run this code through the controller I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in Pagination.php on line 9

Here is the code - line 9 is the line with "ceil" function:

```
class Pagination {
    //The total number of objects that need to paginated
    private $numObjects;
    //The number of objects per page of pagination
    private $objectsPerPage;
    //Total number of pages
    public $numPages = ceil( $numObjects / $objectsPerPage );
    //Number of objects on last page
    public $objectsLastPage = $numObjects % $objectsPerPage;



    //constructor function to populate variables. 
    public function __construct( $numObjects, $objectsPerPage ) {
        $this->numObjects = $numObjects;
        $this->objectsPerPage = $objectsPerPage;
    }
    //end constructor
}
//end Pagination
```

Here is my controller code where I run this:

```
$params = array ( 20, 10 );

$this->load->library('pagination', $params);
```

Comment: You can't use expressions (function calls) for property declarations. Only static values or constant expressions (php5.6+) are allowed. (Use the constructor for such things.)

Comment: yes expression is not allowed, remove those two line `$numPages ` and `$objectsLastPage`.